# How to set View and their controls frames in iOS7?

Tags: ios, layout, frames, autorotate

For rotating views for LandScape to portrait and their corresponding controls like buttons and labels etc..
Actually the **willRotateToInterfaceOrientation** method is not calling in `iOS7`.
I'm using like this for view rotating,

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}
```

I need to set the frames here. How can I achieve this? Please do help. Thanks!

Comment: and this method is applicable in all Views.

Comment: Hi, you can the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` will work in iOS7. I just tried it. Try testing this with breakpoints.

Comment: I think your view controller is not supporting that orientation.i.e this method is not called. Check it.

Comment: I had already check with break points.this method hadn't call.

Comment: Ok Rajath,its working good now. thank u for your guidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set frames for your view, you should access the frame property of your view and replace it with a new frame. For example:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);
yourView.frame = newFrame;
```

Where `newX`, `newY`, `newWidth` and `newHeight` are of type `CGFloat`.
You may do the same for the controls. For example:

```
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Hope this helps!